# Missing Wrap Option in 2.76

Tags: texture-painting

Does anyone know where the wrap option in the texture paint settings has gone? It seems to be missing in 2.76. Was it removed from Blender, or has the button been relocated?

Comment: Do you mean "warp" not "wrap" ?

Answer (score 3):

[The *wrap* setting was moved to separate X and Y tile settings](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.76/More_Features#Sculpting) in *tool shelf > tiling*:

[image]