# Where is Wrap option in UV/Image Editor view?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

In older versions of Blender, if you wanted to draw a seamless texture, you could enable Repeat under Display tab to make the texture square repeat in the UV/Image Edit view, and also enable Wrap checkbox option under Paint Stroke(right under Jitter setting). This would allow you to draw with brushes past the UV box's boundaries and "connect" the seams to make texture essentially seamless(like Offset filter in Photoshop).

Repeat seems to be still available in the Tools panel of Image Editor view, but I can't find Wrap. Somebody mentioned that it's the Tiling setting, but I tried enabling both X and Y and it won't let me draw/paint past the UV box boundaries.

In this question there's an answer with GIF example: [Missing Wrap Option in 2.76](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40798/missing-wrap-option-in-2-76?rq=1)

When I try enabling Tiling, my brush seems to stop a short distance after I pass the borders on the other side and doesn't go any further, unlike the GIF in the linked question.

Where is the Wrap option now?

[image: Older blender Repeat and Wrap]

[image: Tiling enabled on X and Y]

Comment: Tiling X and Y in Tool plus Repeat Image under View tab?

Comment: @CraigDJones I've tried that. If Tiling is suppose to be replacement for Wrap from older version then it kind of works, but unlike in some videos where they paint past the boundaries and blender "wraps" their brush stroke - mine goes a bit further than usual border but stops and I have to go over to opposite side of the texturing square to "connect" both sides to make them seamless. Perhaps this is the intended behavior?